# Multiple aliases in KISSmetrics CSV-import

Tags: api, csv, metrics, kissmetrics

I know you can add an alias field to the data when using the KISSmetrics CSV-import feature: 
http://support.kissmetrics.com/integrations/csv-import/

```
Identity     Alias           Timestamp
gwashdog     gw@example.com  1230768000
abelincoln11 al@example.com  1230768000
mrtaft2      ht@example.com  1230768000
```

But is it possible add several aliases for the same event? Something like:

```
Identity     Alias           Timestamp
gwashdog     gw@example.com  1230768000
gwashdog     gw_alias        1230768000
abelincoln11 al@example.com  1230768000
mrtaft2      ht@example.com  1230768000
mrtaft2      ht_alias        1230768000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can alias together 3 or more ID's to all represent the same person this way. Keep in mind that an ID should not change very often, so it may be sufficient to just set a property for any additional "aliases" you want to store for a given person:

http://support.kissmetrics.com/getting-started/understanding-identities.html#section-3

Comment: I know it is possible when you're using the API, but how do you represent multiple aliases in the CSV? The documentation on importing CSV's only talks about how to deal with a single alias.